# What type of visa to visit USA to compete as an amateur athlete

Tags: visas, usa, sport

As an amateur sporting team visiting the USA for a sporting competition which visa would be appropriate for athletes (unpaid) and for coaches (working, but paid in their country of residence) ?

Comment: What's the sport and the "level" of the athletes? What country are you from (citizenship of all the athletes+coaches)?

Comment: Are you members of an official sport federation? Is the competition you are going to "official" (organized by a sport organization in the USA)?